# JPA Entities not being found

Tags: java, jpa

In my code I use a JPA `EntityManager` to persist objects. Two entities I persist in particular are `Question` and `Response`. I also have a `ResponseDAO` that handles various actions dealing with `Response`s. One of the methods in this DAO is

```
public void setResponse(Question question, String value) {
    Optional<Response> response = getResponse(question);
    if (response.isPresent()) {
        // update existing Response
        response.get().setValue(value);
        entityManager.merge(response.get());
    } else {
        // create new Response
        Response response = createResponse(question, value);
        response = entityManager.merge(response);
        question.getResponses().add(response);
    }
}
```

`Question` has a `responses` field, which is a set of `Response`s – though, with the way the logic is written, the set’s size should never be greater than one. If a `Response` associated with that `Question` is found, `value` should overwrite the previous value; a new `Response` is only created when no `Response` associated with that `Question` is found.

This is not always what I find to be the case, however. Looking in the database, there are some `Question`s that have many `Response`s associated with them. I haven't been able to recreate a situation in which this happens, so It's hard to diagnose the exact cause. My guess is that, occasionally `getResponse()` wont find a `Response` in the database that *should* be there, which may mean that a newly created `Response` might not have been actually persisted in the database by the time `getResponse()` searches for that `Response`. Is that possible? Are there any other plausible explanations?

Comment: Please post the implementation of `getResponse()`, `createResponse()`, and the entity mappings

Comment: Yes, without some more code it would be hard to help you troubleshoot this.